# ImageView position with setIndentationLevel on UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, sdk, uiimageview

I've got small problem with setIndentationLevel on my cell views. I'm setting imageView to cell.imageView like this:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background-for-flags.png"]
```

and indent as random:

```
int random = arc4random() % 10;
[cell setIndentationLevel:random];
```

Result is corrupted view layout like in a screenshot below. Image seems to be always centered in white space (indent area). 
How can I position UIImageView/labels in correct (fixed) location from each other?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by image seems to be always centered? And what do you actually want to achieve? Can you give a mockup of the intended result, e.g. image view and labels in fixed location as you mentioned?

Comment: did you find out the solution?

Comment: Did you got any solution? Please guide if ..... you got it.